# Where is list of theme features in Drupal 8 that can be exposed on the "Settings" page?

Tags: 8

In my theme.info.yml file, I can expose features to show up in the settings of my theme. It's documented here: [drupal.org theming](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/defining-a-theme-with-an-infoyml-file#screenshot)

```
features:
  - comment_user_verification
  - comment_user_picture
  - favicon
  - logo
  - node_user_picture
```

I tried to google a list of these, but can't find it. Is there some way I can figure out all the options available here, if there's not an explicit list anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/config/schema/core.data_types.schema.yml#n172

There needs to be documentation for this. Maybe I'll write it.....